# Database dump cannot be imported

Tags: postgresql

**On the host**:

- CentOS Linux 7 (Core);
- psql (PostgreSQL) 11.16.

**In DBMS**:

- prod_db, size 4004 MB.

I created a database dump: `pg_dump -U postgres -h 192.168.124.115 prod_db > prod_db.dump`.
After that, I delete the database and create an empty database.
After that, I import the database: `pgsql -U postgres prod_db < prod_db.dump`.
At that point, I can get different results. Sometimes the database is imported successfully (40-50 minutes). Sometimes the database is not imported, "gets stuck" (I waited a maximum of 2 days, then interrupted the process).

No errors in logs. No errors in console.
I tried importing with pg_restore: the result is the same.
I tried importing like this `sudo -u postgres psql -U postgres prod_db < prod_db.dump`: the result is the same.
I tried to run the import from another host: the result is the same.

After a few days, I used the `strace`. I have two files with `strace` output: [successful_import.log](https://dropmefiles.com/LrVWx) and [unsuccessful_import.log](https://dropmefiles.com/6KlrG).

If someone can help, I will be very grateful!

P.S.: can provide any additional information.

Updated:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c "SELECT datname,wait_event_type,wait_event FROM pg_stat_activity where datname = 'prod_db';"
   datname   | wait_event_type | wait_event
-------------+-----------------+------------
   prod_db   |                 |
(1 row)
```

Comment: I'm not going to download large binary files from random websites.  Can you include the last dozen lines or so of the unsuccessful one in your post in plain text?

Comment: These are text files in archives.

Answer (score 0):

The load must be divided into two stages: creating a database schema and directly loading data:

1. `sudo -u postgres pg_restore -U postgres --schema-only -d prod_db prod_db.dump`
2. `sudo -u postgres pg_restore -U postgres --data-only --disable-triggers -d prod_db prod_db.dump`

Comment: "Code only answers" are not very beneficial to future visitors.  Please explain what the command does (in your answer).